# Where can I find the list of nouns that are used with zero-article?

Tags: articles, zero-article

Where can I find a list of nouns that are used with a zero-article—that is, words which do not need an article.

For example

> *Milk* is good.
>
> They spoke about *corruption*.

Is there some list of these words so I can memorize them?

Comment: That's not how the definite and indefinite article work. If I say, "**The milk** I bought last night has gone off" I am using the article correctly. I could also claim that "There is **a corruption** at the heart of American politics." The latter was a quote I just copied and pasted from Google.

Comment: Additional information on **a corruption**: I checked with COCA and found that of all 7388 samples, 164 of them have article *"a"*, e.g. *Realism is a corruption of reality.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps you mean **uncountable** nouns.

Usually, you should find a handful of uncountable nouns in any student's grammar books. As for the complete list, I'm afraid that there is no such thing. (If there is such a list somewhere, I would like to know too.)

In my opinion, memorizing them might not the most effective way. I usually consult dictionaries when I am in doubt, and you can do that too. However, you will have to choose well, for only some dictionaries will tell you clearly which noun is countable and which is uncountable. (Also note that several of them can be either countable and uncountable, depending on your specific use.)

For such an online dictionary, I recommend *Macmillan Dictionary*. For example, you can look up the word corruption at: **http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/corruption**. It will tell you exactly that *corruption* is uncountable.

---

Also note that, **the** is a definite article; **a** and **an** are indefinite articles. A singular countable noun **must have** *a*, *an*, or *the* in front of it. (Well, that's the basic idea, because there are exceptions such as *my*, *your*, *that*, etc.) For plural countable nouns and uncountable nouns, you can use either the zero-article or the definite article *the*.

The usage of definite article vs. indefinite article might be too complicated for me to cover all of them here. My suggestion is reading these posts: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/indefinite-article.
<sub>NOTE: There are quite a handful of questions in ELL being tagged with **articles**, **definite-article**, **indefinite-article**, and **zero-article**.</sub>

Comment: +1 just a remark: it's usually, but not always, predictable from the semantics, whether a noun is uncountable or not; simply ask, "can I count this?" For instance, abstract concepts and liquids are always mass nouns (uncountable) and almost all solids are count nouns. As far as I know, the only gray area is small solids, e.g. rice and sand are mass nouns but peas and pebbles are count nouns. (Historically, peas was a mass noun and spelled pease.)

Comment: Also, almost all mass nouns can become count nouns if we are comparing two different types, e.g. the sands of Africa vs. the sands of Asia.

Comment: Some basic words can confuse ELLs quite easily. For example, the word *job* (countable) vs. *work* (uncountable), but then in some context, *work* can be countable too.

Comment: Ah I see. Yes, job is certainly an abstract concept, yet is a count noun. My description above was too simplistic.

Comment: Hmm, so "Darkness is dark." or "The darkness is dark". And why?

Comment: Either. The first is a statement about the nature of darkness. The second is a statement about a specific instance of darkness. You could do the same with milk.

Comment: *"The"* is a definite article; *"a"* and *"an"* are indefinite articles. A singular countable noun must have *"a"*, *"an"*, or *"the"* in front of it. (Well, that's the basic idea, because there are exceptions such as *my*, *your*, *that*, etc.) For a plural countable noun and an uncountable noun, you can use either the zero-article or the definite article *"the"*.

Comment: @hunter pebbles and peas are obviously countable because they are plurals of pea and pebble. The uncountable form of pebble is "gravel". "rices" and "sands" are also count nouns. We could use pea uncountably: "this shepherd's pie is all pea, and no meat".